# Returning values from php file to ajax

Tags: ajax

I have written ajax engine to connect to php file. In php file i am accesing data from database. I want to return the array fetched from database back to ajax engine.. How to return the values..

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials doing what you just asked. Have you searched / tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is join the array with something in your php let's say

```
$return_string=join('||||', $array);
```

Then in the javascript split the response you get

```
var response_array=response.split('||||');
```

Comment: Not that I'm bias towards my answer, but this method is very inefficient if you are using php and javascript. JSON is a well known standard for moving data between languages.

Comment: and I agree, was a fast answer

Answer (score 0):

with JSON :)

```
$json_str = json_encode($arr);
echo $json_str;
```

I assume you are wanting to use the array in another language such as JavaScript.

Decoding in JavaScript is easy: `var arr = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

Hope this helps..